# How can I post an image on Facebook using Python requests and Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

1) I require a function which should publish a post with the given message and photo.
One can use the page ID and access tokens provided in self.page_id and self.page_access_token

```
def __init__(self):
        self.page_id = Facebook.get_access_token('FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID')
        self.page_access_token = Facebook.get_access_token('FACEBOOK_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN')
```

2) To find which API to hit, check out developer section of the Facebook API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#example-2

3) The function should not return anything.

```
def publish_photo_msg(self, message, image_url):
#your code here
return
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

python

```
params = (
    ('access_token', self.page_access_token),
)
```

Next, let us fix the data dictionary:

python

```
data = {
  'url': image_url,
  'caption': 'this is the caption'
}
```

Now, let’s proceed to the URL. There are many ways to set this. Here is one way:

python

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/' + self.page_id + '/photos?access_token=' + self.page_access_token
```

Since we have stored the access_token in the params tuple, let’s make use of it in the `requests.post() call.`

python

```
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/' + self.page_id + '/photos'
response = requests.post(url=url, params=params, data=data)
```

Lastly, you can also verify if your requests.post() call was successful by checking the value of the response variable:

python

```
print response.status_code, response.json()
```

For easy reference, here is the full implementation of the publish_photo_msg function with all the suggestions incorporated:

python

```
params = (
    ('access_token', self.page_access_token),
)
data = {
  'url': image_url,
  'caption': message
}
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/' + self.page_id + '/photos'
response = requests.post(url=url, params=params, data=data)
print(response.status_code, response.json())
```